# Is it possible to reload the main and all files/modules imported during runtime with code?

Tags: python

I want to be able to reload my program by reloading the main function which should reload all the imports that it uses. Is this possible in python?

I know about the .reload() function but that requires the file to have a module and some of my files do not have modules.

Comment: Why can you not just call `main()` in a loop?

Comment: About `.reload()`, you mean `importlib.reload()`? And, mind if you add a bit more detail about why reloading is needed? (or they might close your question forcefully!)  To me. it sounds like you're trying to keep some service up that isn't stable